# how to create dynamic tableview inside dynamic tableview in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, dynamic, tableview

This is what I want to make. 
 I want the `tableview` which is inside, return dynamic count.

For example, 3 rows in first cell, 2 rows in second cell, 4rows in third cell... like this.

And also outside `tableview`'s count is dynamic either.

What should I return `tableView` cell count?

[image]

Comment: You should process each table view delegate separately if you want to do table view in table view. In the cell you should subscribe for second table view and return that count what you need.

Comment: @biloshkurskyi.ss Hi, Thank you for reply. Can you explain more? I can't understand yet ;( Are you mean to create tableview class for inside tableview?

Comment: I dont understand, why you need such functionality. You can use single tableview with multiple sections to achieve same thing.

Comment: @MehulThakkar Can I make dynamic sections and dynamic cells at the same time?

Comment: @poq : yes, why not. You can

Answer (score 0):

you can make your datasource like this:

```
class TableViewDataSource {
   var outerTVDatasource: [OuterTableViewDataSource]?
}

class OuterTableViewDataSource {
   var insideTVDatasource: [InsideTableViewDataSource]?
}

class InsideTableViewDataSource {
}
```

and in main viewcontroller where you have parent tableview,return numberOfRows as

```
class MainViewController: UIVIewController {
  var outerTableView: UITableView?
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
outerTableView.delegate = self
outerTableView.dataSource = self
}
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return tableViewDataSourceObject.outerTVDatasource.count ?? 0
  }

//PseudoCode
func cellForRowAt() {
let cell = dequeue as? OuterTableViewCell
cell.dataSource =  tableViewDataSourceObject.outerTVDatasource
return cell
}

}
```

let your OuterTableViewCell handle inner tableview

```
class OuterTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

var innerTableView: UITableView?
var dataSource: OuterTableViewDataSource?

//psuedo code
awakeFromNib() {
innerTableView.delegate = self
innerTableView.datasource = self
}

    numberOfrow() {
return dataSource. insideTVDatasource.count
}
cellforrow() {
let cell = dequeue as? InnerTableViewCell
cell.dataSource = dataSource. insideTVDatasource
return cell
}


class InnerTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
var dataSource: InsideTableViewDataSource
}
```

Comment: do i have to connect inside tableview's datasouce and delegate at the same viewcontroller with outside tableview?

Comment: where should i create datasource? do i have to create another class? and how can i connect it with inside tableview ??

Comment: thank u, but there is something i can't understand. What is tableViewDataSourceObject?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create 2 Datasource for 2 tableviews. Something just like this:

```
final class YouViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    let outerModel: [Any] = []
    lazy var outerDatasource = OuterTableDatasource(model: self.outerModel)
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.tableView.dataSource = outerDatasource
        self.tableView.delegate = outerDatasource

    }
}

final class CellThatContainTableView: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    var dataSource: InnerTableDatasource! {
        didSet {
            self.tableView.dataSource = dataSource
            self.tableView.delegate = dataSource
        }
    }
    func configure(dataSource: InnerTableDatasource) {
        self.dataSource = dataSource
    }
}

final class OuterTableDatasource: NSObject {
    var model: [Any]
    init(model: [Any]) {
        self.model = model
    }
}

extension OuterTableDatasource: UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return model.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        //implement cell configuration
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! CellThatContainTableView
        cell.configure(dataSource: InnerTableDatasource(model: []))
        return cell
    }


}
extension OuterTableDatasource: UITableViewDelegate {

}

final class InnerTableDatasource: NSObject {
    var model: [Any]
    init(model: [Any]) {
        self.model = model
    }
}

extension InnerTableDatasource: UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return model.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        //implement cell configuration
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")!


        return cell
    }


}
extension InnerTableDatasource: UITableViewDelegate {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Check this blog post for details** : https://medium.com/@stasost/ios-how-to-build-a-table-view-with-multiple-cell-types-2df91a206429

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   let item = items[indexPath.section]
   switch item.type {
   case .nameAndPicture:
      if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: NamePictureCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as? NamePictureCell {
         cell.item = item
         return cell
      }
   case .about:
      if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: AboutCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as? AboutCell {
         cell.item = item
         return cell
      }
   case .email:
      if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: EmailCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as? EmailCell {
         cell.item = item
         return cell
      }
   case .friend:
      if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: FriendCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as? FriendCell {
         cell.item = friends[indexPath.row]
         return cell
      }
   case .attribute:
      if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: AttributeCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as? AttributeCell {
         cell.item = attributes[indexPath.row]
         return cell
      }
   }
   // return the default cell if none of above succeed
   return UITableViewCell()
}

You can use the same structure to setup the didSelectRowAt delegate method:
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
      switch items[indexPath.section].type {
          // do appropriate action for each type
      }
}
```